# Sharepoint Online - Automatically take value of one field/column into another field/column

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am an o365 SP Online newbie so please bear with me as I try and learn this.

I have 2 fields called Title and Equipment Name.

The Equipment Name is a required field so the user has to enter something there.

How or where can I set in SP Online where if a user enters something in the "Equipment Name" field, the value entered would automatically be entered in the :Title" field?

If user enters:

Equipment Name: sump pump

then

Title: sump pump

How can I do that? Do I make the Title field a calculated value?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that a calculated column would work. If you make the Title column or the Equipment Name column a "calculated column" and set the formula to be "=[column name here]" then that column will auto-populate with the value of the column in the formula

Comment: Hmmm.. I got an error "Sorry, something went wrong ...
The formula contains reference(s) to field(s)." In the Title field, I entered =[Equipment Name]

Comment: It sounds as though you edited one of the existing columns and put the formula in either the Column Validation formula field or made the Default Value field a Calculated Value and entered that formula. Unfortunately those options won't work. You will have to create a new column (type = Calculated) and enter the formula in the Formula field

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Calculated Column called Title and set the formula "=[Column name here]".

In your case it will =[Equipment Name]

[Calculated Column Tutorial](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/sharepoint/calculated-columns-in-sharepoint-2010/)